# Will IHostedService be stopped gracefully on SIGTERM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get info on how asp net core handles stopping IHostedService.

On my machine, if I have an app executing with an IHostedService, and if I send to it SIGTERM, I observe that StopAsync() method is called as expected, with cancellation tokens changed etc, so my code can gracefully handle the SIGTERM.
However, if I try on another environment, it seems that on SIGTERM the IHostedService is brutally stopped, without calling the StopAsync() code. So I have a feeling this depends on the version and potentially env (macos vs linux)

Is there a documented behavior for what Asp .net core will consider "graceful" shutdown demand, depending on the asp .net core version etc ? I couldn't find anything. Ideally it should be documented what's the behavior of IHostedService when SIGTERM is sent

Comment: The BackgroundService and Worker Service docs actually cover this. This is handled by the host, not the services.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos they seem to only mention "graceful shutdown" but they don't mention what constitutes a "graceful shutdown"

Comment: They do. `StopAsync` is called and the CancellationToken passed to IHostedService methods is triggered. It's up to the services to actually monitor the cancellation tokens and exit

Comment: My question is , what is at the origin of  a "graceful shutdown"  ? is SIGTERM included ? Since what version ?

Comment: StopAsync is called when the host stops. Host shutdown is described in  the [Host Shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#host-shutdown) section of the Generic Host docs, including how SIGTERM is handled. You need to specify `ConsoleLifetime` to enable SIGTERM, SIGKILL monitoring. Way back when that was done using the  `RunConsole` extension method

Comment: `Since what version` since the generic host was added, before .NET Core 3.1. The docs have moved around though and some things haven't made it to the latest version. Way back when, some things were only mentioned in samples and blog posts. [RunConsoleAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) will call [UseConsoleLifetime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useconsolelifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) internally bef. Run

Comment: The docs are spread across generic .NET Core and ASP.NET Core sections, so it takes a bit of time to find the correct pages :(

Comment: thank you !
So actually the difference I think in my case is that in some case, I have "ConsoleLifetime" and not in another env. But how can I choose to activate (or not) "ConsoleLifetime" ? seems like internal implementation

Comment: I pulled together the docs sections.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem. It is not working with me, I am using .NET 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Version**

Use [RunConsoleAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead of `Run` or `RunAsync`.

Another option is to call [UseConsoleLifetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useconsolelifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) before calling one of the other methods. `RunConsoleAsync()` does this internally

Since .NET 6, graceful shutdown isn't used when `Environment.Exit()` called from the application itself.

**Explanation**

`StopAsync` will be called when the Host shuts down. Normally, SIGTERM or SIGKILL aren't monitored unless the host runs with a Console lifetime. This is a feature of the Generic Host that was added in .NET Core 3 and replaced the older WebHost. The ASP.NET Core docs were updated and new docs added in the generic .NET sections

Unfortunately, this means that Host and middleware behavior is duplicated and even *spread* across different sections.

The shutdown behavior, especially regarding SIGTERM, MacOS, Linux etc is described in the [Host Shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#host-shutdown) section. If `ConsoleLifetime` is used, SIGTERM, SIGKILL etc are monitored. That section doesn't say how to do this though.

This is documented in the [.NET Generic Host for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0) page, in the [RunConsoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#runconsoleasync) section :

> RunConsoleAsync enables console support, builds and starts the host, and waits for Ctrl+C/SIGINT (Windows), ⌘+C (macOS), or SIGTERM to shut down.

When Console Lifetime is used, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL, will result in a graceful shutdown :

> If ConsoleLifetime is used, it listens for the following signals and attempts to stop the host gracefully.
>
> - SIGINT (or CTRL+C).
> - SIGQUIT (or CTRL+BREAK on Windows, CTRL+\ on Unix).
> - SIGTERM (sent by other apps, such as docker stop).

`Environment.Exit` though isn't a graceful shutdown. This caused problems before .NET 6 :

> Before .NET 6, there wasn't a way for .NET code to gracefully handle SIGTERM. To work around this limitation, ConsoleLifetime would subscribe to System.AppDomain.ProcessExit. When ProcessExit was raised, ConsoleLifetime would signal the host to stop and block the ProcessExit thread, waiting for the host to stop.

> This caused other issues because SIGTERM wasn't the only way ProcessExit was raised. It is also raised by code in the application calling Environment.Exit. Environment.Exit isn't a graceful way of shutting down a process in the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting app model.

This changed in .NET 6:

> In .NET 6, POSIX signals are supported and handled. This allows for ConsoleLifetime to handle SIGTERM gracefully, and no longer get involved when Environment.Exit is invoked.

And

> For .NET 6+, ConsoleLifetime no longer has logic to handle scenario Environment.Exit. Apps that call Environment.Exit and need to perform clean-up logic can subscribe to ProcessExit themselves. Hosting will no longer attempt to gracefully stop the host in this scenario.